# How to create PDF document using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

How to create PDF document using iPhone SDK?

Any tutorials and examples to do this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quartz 2D Apple tutorial

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101

Answer (score 5):

Theres a great open source api for creating PDFs. You can add text, images, and headers to the PDF, and then either send the PDF or save it to a file.
The Api is at http://code.google.com/p/pdf-api-iphonesdk/wiki/PDFAPI
If you have any questions about it, the support is great, just contact maor.kern@mobice.org

Answer (score 4):

You can use UIKit to generate a pdf. Its really simple. You just have to start a pdf context and write out contents to it:

See this: http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)generatePdfButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
}
- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    NSInteger currentPage = 0;
    BOOL done = NO;
    do
    {
        // Mark the beginning of a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

        // Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
        currentPage++;
        [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

        //Draw a border for each page.
        [self drawBorder];

        //Draw text fo our header.
        [self drawHeader];

        //Draw a line below the header.
        [self drawLine];

        //Draw some text for the page.
        [self drawText];

        //Draw an image
        [self drawImage];
        done = YES;
    }
    while (!done);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
- (void) drawBorder
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(kBorderInset, kBorderInset, pageSize.width-kBorderInset*2, pageSize.height-kBorderInset*2);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, borderColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kBorderWidth);
    CGContextStrokeRect(currentContext, rectFrame);
}
- (void) drawLine
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kLineWidth);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(kMarginInset + kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(pageSize.width - 2*kMarginInset -2*kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    CGContextClosePath(currentContext);
    CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
- (void) drawText
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    NSString *textToDraw = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.";

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset)
                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect
                  withFont:font
             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
                 alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}
- (void) drawImage
{
    UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"];
    [demoImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - demoImage.size.width/2)/2, 350, demoImage.size.width/2, demoImage.size.height/2)];
}
```